# The Oracle Problem, as it relates to testing

Tags: testing, math, logic

I'm brushing up on my software testing theory and came across an interesting phenomenon called the Oracle problem. I've picked up bits and pieces as to what the problem alludes to but haven't yet pieced it all together.

One rather dark version of the problem goes a little something like this:
An island has 100 inhabitants. Each of the inhabitants has either green or blue eyes. None of the inhabitants are allowed to communicate with each other to let them know what color eyes they have, nor are there any reflective surfaces in which the inhabitants can see their own eye colors. Basically everyone knows what color eyes everyone has but none of them know what color eyes they themselves have. The rule on the island is that if you find out that you have blue eyes you must kill yourself. The island's population remains stable until one day an oracle arrives and tells the inhabitants that some people on the island have blue eyes.

The question is what happens to the people?

An answer I found is that 100 days later the last person on the island kills themselves.

I have no clue how this makes sense and I was hoping that someone could help relate this problem back to software testing. Thanks for coming on the journey and I look forward to some interesting responses.

Comment: Indeed, I'd really like to see this problem related to software testing!

Comment: It is a fun question but I struggle to see how it relates to programming - your question is basically 'how does this relate to programming', right?

Comment: @Kirk Broadhurst not only am I interested in how this relates to software testing theory but I am equally interested in understanding the problem from a logical point.

Comment: Further, I think you have the problem wrong.   If you know there are `n` blue eyed people, but you only see `n-1` around you, then you know you must have blue eyes.  The correct problem is that there are (unknown number) of blue eyed people. http://www.cs.columbia.edu/~evs/intro/Oracle.html

Comment: Is there any stackexchange site related to such puzzle questions?

Comment: @Kirk Broadhurst thanks for that tip, I was just editing the post to reflect that change while you posted your comment.

Comment: The only Oracle problem I am aware of that relates to programming is the fact that it can't tell the difference between an empty string and a NULL value :-)

Comment: @Bnjmn It is doesn't relate to programming then it's off topic.  Unfortunately this isn't really a place for 'logic puzzles'

Comment: @Kirk Broadhurst So, going by the logic that n people are on the island and n-1 people are visible to you, the first person looks around and notices that 99 other people have green eyes so he kills himself. The next day everyone else on the island looks around and sees only green eyed people and so they assume they have blue eyes as well and kill themselves, and so on and so forth???

Comment: How is this even a little bit software related?

Comment: @Bnjmn No; if you read the link above you'll understand that all the blue eyed people realise they are blue eyed on the same day (as would be rational).

Comment: @Kirk Broahhurst Thanks for the play by play, makes a lot more sense now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, to understand the puzzle, add one detail: if you find out that you have blue eyes, you commit suicide at midnight, in privacy. Nobody knows you're dead until morning. Now try a few versions of the problem with fewer people:

1. There is only one inhabitant. The oracle arrives and says "there is at least one inhabitant with blue eyes". The outcome should be obvious.

   There are two inhabitants. Again, the oracle says "there is at least one inhabitant with blue eyes. Try to figure out what might happen. Is it possible that neither of them dies on the first night?

   Now try three inhabitants, same pronouncement from the oracle.

   Now three, but the oracle says "there are at least two inhabitants with blue eyes".

And so on. You may have noticed that the oracle must have an interesting property for this to work: it is truthful, and *everybody knows about this property*. This means that everyone knows that everyone knows that the oracle is truthful, and everyone knows it, and so on. The fact of a death is also **common knowledge**: if Sam dies in the night, everyone knows that he killed himself, and everyone knows that everyone else knows it, and so on.

So what does this have to do with software testing? I don't consider it a very good analogy, but the idea is that you can test a piece of software against something, some standard, to see if it gives the correct answer. The standard might be another piece of software, or the same software in a previous run, or theoretical results, or whatever. But how do we know the standard is correct? It would be really good to have a standard which is correct, and which everyone knows is correct, and which *everyone knows* everyone knows is correct, and so on.

**EDIT:**
P.S.: there may be some confusion because in computer science the term "oracle" also refers to a theoretical device that can solve problems which a Turing machine cannot solve, such as the Halting Problem.